# Javascript mousemove events not trapping on 64 bit browsers under Win7/8

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, 64-bit, mousemove

I've stuck a problem which appears to occur only with 64 bit browsers under Win7 and 8.

My application uses "JQuery Slider" (see http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/) which works fine under all the test environments available to me--I develop under OS-X testing on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on that platform, the same three on XP-SP3, and Safari under IOS.

Some users (and the customer) have demonstrated that the slider does not move under the Chrome, Firefox, and Safari under Windows 7. Using Opera however, the slider behaves as expected.  It appears that the common factor is 64 bit browsers and 64 bit MS OS's. Strangely, the sliders work under IE, but the application, developed for a University, is not required to support any version of IE.

I've instrumented the function which responds to mousemove events and determined that it does not fire on the problem systems.

The bind code is :

```
this._bindEvent( $( document ), "move", function( event ){
    if( self.is.drag ){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        self._mousemove( event );
    }
});
```

Which looks reasonable to me (apart from the spacing ;-), and certainly works well under all my test environments.

My question:  has anyone experienced similar problems, or know of special requirements under 64 bit browsers?

My application is located at [PaperMiner.org.au](http://paperminer.org.au) and you can try the sliders without registering or anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been located.  JQuery Slider responds to either clicks and touch events.  The code looks like this:

```
    this.supportTouches_ = 'ontouchend' in document;
    this.events_ = {
      "click": this.supportTouches_ ? "touchstart" : "click",
      "down": this.supportTouches_ ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
      "move": this.supportTouches_ ? "touchmove" : "mousemove",
      "up"  : this.supportTouches_ ? "touchend" : "mouseup"
    };
```

On 64 bit versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari running under a MS Windows 7 and 8, this test reports "true", so the code then waits for events which will never trigger.  The real problem is the test which needs to be more rigorous so only actual touch driven devices bind the "touch*" events.  Question 4817029 has some answers, but testing suggests recent browser releases have negated the solutions found there.  Testing for IOS or Android might be more reliable...